# ‘class shape’ has no member named ‘info’ but adding one doesn't work either

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-base-class

I'm trying to get some code to compile ([This code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7168027/)) but when I comment out line 25:
`virtual void info()=0;`
it doesn't compile:

```
shape.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
shape.cpp:345:11: error: ‘class shape’ has no member named ‘info’
  svec[0]->info();
```

but keeping line 25 gives a very long error about a pure virtual function...

```
shape.cpp:77:15: error: cannot declare parameter ‘squ’ to be of abstract type ‘square’
   cube(square squ):
               ^
shape.cpp:30:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘square’:
 class square : public shape {
       ^
shape.cpp:25:16: note:  virtual void shape::info()
   virtual void info()=0;
                ^
shape.cpp:167:20: error: cannot declare parameter ‘rec’ to be of abstract type ‘rectangle’
   cuboid(rectangle rec, double d):
                    ^
shape.cpp:110:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘rectangle’:
 class rectangle : public shape {
       ^
shape.cpp:25:16: note:  virtual void shape::info()
   virtual void info()=0;
```

and so on...

Can anyone give me an idea about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is declared `const` in the derived classes, but not in the base class. This means that the derived classes don't override the function; they just declare a different function with the same name.

Either add `const` in the base class, or remove it in the derived classes.

Comment: Thank you Mike, that fixed the problem! I'll accept your answer as soon as it will let me